# Logic Testing in Xcode: Stop the chain of imports

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, import, xcode6, ocmock

I'm unit testing a class that has a couple of big imports (which themselves have a lot of imports).

ex:

```
//  ObjectIWouldLikeToTest.m

#import "AnalyticsPackage.h"
#import "KitchenSink.h"
```

I don't want it to import all these complicated classes when I'm running logic tests. Is there a way to mock out these imports using OCMock for example?

In the future I want to simplify my design so it has better dependencies. But, while I refactor, I want to have basic unit tests (to quickly catch any bugs I introduce).

Comment: Why are you worried about the imports? Compile time, even for very large apps, isn't a big deal for Objective-C software.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen When running logic tests, I'd rather not compile the whole app. It's the difference between a second and 16 seconds. I'd like my tests to run fast to encourage constant testing.

Comment: But you're not compiling the whole app. You're compiling the test-target, which only includes the implementation files (.m/.cpp) you selected for that target. You can't use OCMock to fake a implementation file, but you can create a MyTypeMock.m that's only present in the test-target if you want to.